# Settings JAVA_HOME with batch

Tags: windows, batch

At my work, I need to use multiple versions of Java, depending on which project I work on. I've made a batch script to take care of this. There are several different actions that you can perform with the script.

You can change the current value of your `JAVA_HOME` from a version in your file. You can add new Java installation (pre-installed one), you can remove them and you can list them. You can echo your `env` variable, if you're not sure what's the value at the moment.

This is a script I'm using for myself for the time being, so there are a lot of things that are probably not robust or are not yet implemented. For example, you can use the program with non-existent version and it will not crash or warn you. The add and remove functions work but they output the command and can surely be played with. It does work when you know what to do.

This is the first time I'm writing a batch script, and I must say it is mostly been googling and hacking something together.

```
@ECHO OFF
if "%1"=="" goto empty
if "%1"=="echo" goto output
if "%1"=="e" goto output
if "%1"=="list" goto list
if "%1"=="l" goto list
if "%1"=="add" goto add
if "%1"=="a" goto add
if "%1"=="remove" goto remove
if "%1"=="r" goto remove

rem To escape '%' the sequence is '%%', so to not have to have an arg like %JAVA6%, the following will add % % on both end of the argument
SET java_version=%%%1%%

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (%~dp0java_versions.store) do (
   set "%%~a=%%b"
)
call :unquote JAVA_HOME %java_version%

for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (%~dp0java_versions.store) do (
  set "%%a="
)

goto :EOF

:unquote
  set %1=%~2
  goto :output

:output
  ECHO "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%"
  SET "java_version="
  goto :EOF

:list
  FOR /f "delims=" %%x IN (%~dp0java_versions.store) DO (
    echo "%%~x"
  )
  goto :EOF

:add
  if "%2"=="" (
    ECHO "Name of the entry missing"
    goto :EOF
  )
  if "%~3"=="" (
    ECHO "Path of the entry missing"
    goto :EOF
  )
  echo %~3
  IF EXIST %~3 (
    echo %2="%~3">> %~dp0java_versions.store
    ECHO %2="%~3" added
  ) ELSE (
    ECHO %3 is not an actual folder
  ) .
  goto :EOF

:remove
  if "%2"=="" (
    ECHO "Name of the entry missing as an argument of the batch"
    goto :EOF
  )
  set "found="
  for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (%~dp0java_versions.store) do (
     if "%2"=="%%a" (
       set found=1
       echo found
     )
  )
  if defined found  (
    for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%a in (%~dp0java_versions.store) do (
      if NOT "%2"=="%%a" (
        echo %%~a=%%b>> %~dp0new_java_versions.store
      )
    )
    xcopy %~dp0new_java_versions.store %~dp0java_versions.store /y
    del %~dp0new_java_versions.store /f /q
    ECHO Entry %2 deleted
  )

  goto :EOF

:empty
  ECHO "Empty argument, please provide an argument"
  goto :EOF
```

Store file format :

```
JAVA8_11="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11"
JAVA8="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73"
JAVA7="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_51"
```